# State attribute doesn't get updated when route param changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following `<Route>`:

```
<Route path="/sandbox/:test" component={ManagementSandboxPage}/>
```

And 2 pages:

```
class SandboxPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        test: this.props.test
    }
}

render() {
    let {test} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <Link key={1} to={{pathname: "/sandbox/1"}}
                      style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
                    <li>
                        First
                    </li>
                </Link>
                <Link key={2} to={{pathname: "/sandbox/2"}}
                      style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
                    <li>
                        Second
                    </li>
                </Link>
                <div>
                    {test}
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

And

```
class ManagementSandboxPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}
render() {
    return (
        <SandboxPage test={this.props.match.params.test}/>
    );
}
}
```

The `test` state from `SandboxPage` doesn't get updated when I'm switching between `localhost:3000/sandbox/1` and `localhost:3000/sandbox/2`. I've tried with componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate but nothing works.. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is called an anti-pattern and that is to assign a state property the value of a prop. The state of a component should be independent of the rest of the application unless told to behave that way. Try assigning the value of the prop directly into the render method like this.

```
class SandboxPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    let {test} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <Link key={1} to={{pathname: "/sandbox/1"}}
                      style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
                    <li>
                        First
                    </li>
                </Link>
                <Link key={2} to={{pathname: "/sandbox/2"}}
                      style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
                    <li>
                        Second
                    </li>
                </Link>
                <div>
                    {test}
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works. Remember to use console.log to debug your code always. It's a simple but effective way to know exactly at what point does your app has the error.

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thank you for your advice! I'm new in this "React" world. It worked! And of course I'm using "console.log()" for debugging, but I just couldn't figure out what and where is the problem.